# GnuPG PHP Module: Check key passphrase

Tags: php, gnupg, pecl

When I run `gnupg_adddecryptkey` with a correct key identifier, but wrong passphrase, it does not fail, but returns `true`:

```
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,"8660281B6051D071D94B5B230549F9DC851566DC","correctpassphrase"); // true
gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,"WRONGKEYIDENTIFIER","correctpassphrase"); // false
gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,"8660281B6051D071D94B5B230549F9DC851566DC","wrongpassphrase"); // true
```

So how to check a key passphrase of gnupg key in PHP?

Comment: Please remember, we are coders, we work better if we see code that if you tell us a story

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: Maybe have a look of the [comment of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-init.php), It looks like if you didn't set the correct environment, you may have issue to call the gpg function.